# Partition of integers

Tags: number-theory, integers

I was reading the explanation for the formula of the number of sums of consecutive integers that results in $N$. On: http://mathpages.com/home/kmath107.htm

How could:
$$N = n(n+1)/2 - m(m+1)/2$$

Turn into this:
$$m = \frac{-1 + \sqrt { 1 - 4[ 2N - n(n+1) ] }}{2}$$

Please, I'm new on number theory.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! See this link for a quick guide on how to format your equations: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand. What could be the problem?

$$N=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$$

It's the same thing.

$$2N=(n-m)(n+m+1)$$

$2N - $ to factor and find $n,m$ .  To solve the system of linear equations.

Answer (score 2):

Your first equation is a quadratic equation in $n$.
Rearrange it, and apply the standard quadratic solution.

Comment: or complete the square